# Can we find xpath of a text in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, chrome-web-driver

Consider following table in webpage
[image]

I want to know which are all companies are from country UK.
So i have input as UK 
Can i find the xpath of this 'UK' by selenium python so that i can modify that xpath to get related output.
Is this possible, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I will give UK as input, I have to find corresponding companies in UK
Answer : 
If table contains only texts, then
`xpath = "//td[text()='Country']/preceding-sibling::td"` 
If table elements are having links to other pages
xpath - `"//a[text()='Country']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td"` , then select ur element of ur choice to find answer

If ur not sure about using text , u can use 
`//TAG[contains(text(),'TEXT')]`

U can test ur xpaths in Google Chrome's "Developer Console" 
`$any_variable("xpath")`

Interested can go through https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#id-introduction to know how to query XPaths

Thanks

Comment: Please [EDIT] your question and post DOM of that table as well your code trail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose HTML like:

```
<tr>
 <td>
     Island Trading
 </td>
 <td>
     Helen Bennet
 </td>
 <td>
     UK
 </td>
</tr>
......  (more rows)
```

```
# Make a for to get all TDs of each "important" TR, that is, 
# a TR that includes a TD with 'UK' text
for actualRow in self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='UK']/parent::tr/td"):
    # Now select only the first TD
    thisRowsTD=actualRow[0]
    # Print information you need here (Text, id, name...)
    print(thisRowsTD.text)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @nugbe It worked. As i have mentioned wrong code above it had some conflicts. But Thanks it helped me to figure out the problem i am facing. i forgot to mentioned that those are not text but actually links in the table. I used xpath as <code>"//a[text()='Country']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td"</code>. Then i found 1st element in the result

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using `text` attribute, let's say the element containing country name is `td`.
Then you can find all elements with UK text through :

```
elements= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='UK']")
```